# Add HTTP authentication to wp-login.php and wp-admin vps wide

Tags: authentication, vps, http

In order to protect customer's WordPress installs and the vps itself, i would like to know how i can add "HTTP authentication" to wp-login.php and wp-admin folder vps wide, for each WordPress install.

I know it is possible without having to edit each .htaccess file and adding .htpasswd to each install, as i have seem similarly secured wordpress sites before. But i don't know how to implement it on a vps and can't find an instruction online.

VPS specs: CentOs 6.5 Apache 2.4 DirectAdmin Custombuild 2.0

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<Location /your-wp-page >` directive in apache (httpd.conf) 
So you can use something similar in nginx.

Comment: What is the code that i should type in httpd.conf to enable this extra login screen?

Comment: <Location /your_location>      AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Authenticate yourself"
    AuthUserFile /LOCATION_FOR_PASSWORD_FILE
    Require valid-user
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all </Location> And you should use the htpasswd to create the file as htpasswd /file YOUR_USER